# How to get the selected value in the controller using combo itemId in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect, extjs4.2

Can anybody tell me how to get the selected value in a controller using combo itemId in extjs?

I have tried it this way:

```
Ext.getCmp('itemId').getValue(); //this is not working
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to read the docs. [getCmp()](http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp) looks up components by ***id only***. If you want to lookup a component by itemId, use [ComponentQuery](http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery), or [getComponent()](http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.AbstractPanel-method-getComponent).